# Turbolinks/Fastclick - Touch event 'passes through' to the next page when using the transition cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, fastclick.js

I'm using Turbolinks 3.0 on iOS with Fastclick to remove the 300ms iOS delay, with the transition cache enabled. This provides a really great/instant experience with Rails on mobile devices.

I have a link on both pages in the same place, and when I press the link on one page, fastclick+turbolinks loads the next page instantly - but the event passes through to the next page and the link on that page gets clicked too, triggering both links and navigating pages twice.

The event will actually pass through to anything thats in the same place (if I click a link and a form input is on the same place on the next page loaded, it will focus on the input).

I can actually do a 'faster tap' with my finger to prevent it from happening. Its only when the tap is more sluggish (it lasts longer) that it happens.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tons of depressing debugging and thinking over the past few days, this solution seems to work (but is very hack-ish):

JS:

```
$(document).on("page:restore", function() {
  $("body").prepend("<div id='ghost-blocker' onclick='return false;'></div>");
  setTimeout(function() {
   $("#ghost-blocker").remove();
  }, 300);
});
```

CSS:

```
#ghost-blocker {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

I basically debugged all the callbacks with alerts and saw that the last thing that happened after loading the page from the cache but before the ghost click fired was the page:restore function. I made a blocker div that covers the whole screen and cancels out any click event, then removed it 300ms later. This does the job, albeit sloppily. The page:restore callback is also a great time to reset the page in any other way that you need, such as resetting loader images that were left over (I'm using ladda).

I'm now going to try to dive deeper and attempt to catch the ghost click event and prevent it from happening instead of manipulating the DOM with a whole div. If anyone has any insight on how to do this, I'd love to hear.